# MySQLi fetch returning same values when put into an array

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, fetch

I have the following code snippet. The problem is that when I print out the results of the array, the data for the `$results` is the same. It should say `[emaid_id] => 1 and [email_id] => 2`.

How can I fix this problem?

I'm using this code:

```
$ex = $stmt->execute();

$stmt->store_result();

$results = array();
$allResults = array();
$params = array();

$meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
if ($meta)
{
    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field())
    {
        $allResults[$field->name] = null;
        $params[] = &$allResults[$field->name];
    }
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);
}

while ($stmt->fetch())
{
    $results[] = $allResults;
}

$stmt->free_result();
print_r($results);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [email_id] => 2
                    [email_sent] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [email_id] => 2
                    [email_sent] => 0
                )
        )
    [success] => 1
    [count] => 2
)
```

Comment: as stated here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#92505 it will not work :|

Comment: How does your SELECT statement look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by changed my fetch loop to this:

```
$i = 0;
while ($stmt->fetch())
{
    foreach ($allResults as $key => $value)
    {
        $results[$i][$key] = $value;
    }
    $i++;
}
```